# Addons path in my openerp-server.conf isn't exist

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I need to install new modules in Odoo 8
so I fetched the openerp-server.conf which is located in `odoo/debian/openerp-server.conf`.
Here's its content:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
```

I went to addons_path through my terminal, and found out that there is no such file or directory `/openerp/addons` inside dist-packages.

Is my insallation of Odoo is corrupted?.. Should I reinstall it?
If so, how do I clean uninstall Odoo 8 from my Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: you install odoo .deb file? or direct get the source of odoo?

Comment: I installed it from github https://github.com/odoo/odoo --branch 8.0

Answer (score 0):

**Nightly repositories**

To benefit from the best experience of our nightlies, you should use our repositories. They are available for Debian (and similar distributions like Ubuntu) and RedHat distributions (esp. Centos and Fedora). Using an Odoo nightly repository, you will be able to install and upgrade Odoo with the help of your traditional package manager (apt or yum).

If you plan to run the PostgreSQL cluster on the same host than the Odoo one, install PostgreSQL before. This way, Odoo will be able to create and configure its user.
If you want to use a nightly repository for the 7.0 version, the name of the package is openerp.

**Setup of the Debian nightly repository details**

```
wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
```

**Setup of the RedHat nightly repository details**

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo=https://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/rpm/odoo.repo
yum update && yum install odoo
```

if Do that why to install odoo then default path of the odoo is

```
  addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
```

**and you clone into the github so run your like that**

```
   openerp: addons paths: [u'/home/xyz/odoo/master-test/openerp/addons', u'/home/xyz/odoo/master-test/addons']
```

so no need to uninstall odoo and keep run the ODOO.

Thank you may be this is help full you.

Answer (score 0):

Your addons path in ubuntu is /opt/odoo/addons u have to change it in configuration file.Here is a [link](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2014/09/how-to-install-openerp-odoo-8-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/) on how to install odoo in ubuntu